# Trying to generate random int from a class

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to implement a neural network in C++.
I've created a class "neural", each neural has a vector of weight define like this :

```
std::vector <float> weight;
```

I would like to create in my main fonction a vector of neurals. Each neural has to have its weight vector fill randomly.

Here is how I've tried :

each neurals has a methode to fill the weight vector

```
void neural::fillWeight(int numWeight)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numWeight; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "on viens de mettre un poid dans le vecteur" << std::endl;
        this->poid.push_back(rand());
    }
}
```

I call it here:

```
std::vector <neural> vectN ; 

for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    neural test = neural(i, 1, 4);
    vectN.push_back(test);
}
```

The problem is that every neural in the vector have the same weight vector. 
How can I solve this issue ?
Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This is just three snippets of code that don’t relate to each other in any way so it’s impossible to understand what’s happening

Comment: Call `srand` only *once*. Otherwise you reset the seed each time.

Comment: Also, C++ have much better [pseudo-random generation functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than the old `srand` and `rand` functions inherited from C.

Comment: Concerning `srand()`: ...and the chances are high that every call of `srand(time(NULL))` gets the same time (in seconds). Hence, the `rand()` starts always with same seed and produces the same sequence of "random" numbers. (That's why it is called [Pseudo Random Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).)

Comment: And a side lesson: If you watch this in the debugger (step by step), it might seem to work because, in this case, the execution is slowed down that much that you achieve different seeds. That about debugging, if relevant code behavior depends on time... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff that time to use a debugger can mask the problem because the result of `time()` can change because of steps / breakpoints introducing delay :-)

Comment: @bruno: Indeed, that brings back some bad memories.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry to recall you of that ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `srand(time(NULL));` **one time** in *main* for instance, else because your program is probably very fast at the execution you stay on the same second and you reinit the rand sequence to redo the same thing in `neural::fillWeight`

Answer (score 2):

A few issues here.

1. Calling `srand(time(NULL));` in `fillWeight` will introduce significant (perfect in your case!) correlation between the vectors.
2. Judging by your class you might need to use a thread-safe technique. Even the modern C++11 random number libraries are not thread safe.
3. `rand`, although useful in many instances, has its statistical shortcomings.
4. `rand` returns an integral type, judging by the name don't you need a number in [0, 1)?

If you are able to live with (3) - and you may well be able to do if you are setting up an "untrained" network - then one way of addressing these points is to pass a *seed* to `fillWeight` and use a *quick and dirty* generator for those terms:

```
void neural::fillWeight(int numWeight, std::uint32_t I){
for (size_t i = 0; i < numWeight; i++){
    std::cout << "Some fancy French" << std::endl;
    this->poid.push_back(1.0f * I / std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max());
    I = 1664525 * I + 1013904223; // Donald Knuth's numbers.
}
```

Adjust the conversion to `float` if you want negative numbers or a different range. You then use an "outer" Mersenne-Twister generator to generate the `I`s that you pass to the functions.

If this doesn't have adequate statistical properties then you might need to use a "global" Mersenne Twister generator.

Answer (score 0):

use random defined in `#include <random>` and for initialization do this

```
std::default_random_engine engine((std::random_device())());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> rand_dist(0, std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max());
```

get a random int by calling

(random int)  `rand_int = rand_dist(engine);`

you may need to add `<limits>` also

Comment: Op probably wants a uniform float, not a uniform int.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't solve the problem. I had to put the srand(time(NULL))  oly one time in the main